# Target specific tab with hyperlink from other page on same website

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I've got a page (documents.php) that contains four tabs, the 1st tab is set as the default and opens when one browses to documents.php

I need to be able to target tabs 2, 3 and 4 directly from hyperlinks on my index.php and a JavaScript menu that appears on all pages on the site.

Example:

Tab 3 on documents.php contains "archived documents".

On Index.php I want to place a link called "Click here to go to Archived documents" and when someone clicks on it it must take them to documents.php but automatically go to Tab 3 which is "archived documents" and not go to the default 1st Tab.

Here is the coding I am using to create the Tabs and would like to only modify this at most (and not re-invent the wheel by using jQuery or other technology and re-write the tabs on this and other pages):

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#tab1">General Documents</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Circulars</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Newsletters</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Archived Documents</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".tabs li").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".tab-content").hide();
  var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
  $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass("current");
   return false;
    });
});</script>
```

Then there's some CSS in an external style sheet that formats the Tabs, their borders, background etc.

**CSS Formatting:**

```
.tabs ul{
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index:99;
    position:relative;
}
.tabs li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    border-top:#E5E5E5 1px solid;
    border-left:#E5E5E5 1px solid;
    border-right:#E5E5E5 1px solid;
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;    
    color: #444444;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
    margin: 0px 6px 0px 0px;
    background: #e7e7e7 url(/assets/images/common/bg.png) repeat-x;
}

.tabs li:hover {

/*If you want hover effects on tabs put your css here*/

}
.tabs li a {
    display:block;
    color:#323234;
    outline:none;
}

.tabs li.current {
    border-bottom:#DD6E27 2px solid;
    outline:none;
}

.tab-content {
    display:none;
    clear:both;
    min-height: 120px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    color:#444444;
      background:#fefefe url(/assets/images/common/bg.png) repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:15px;
}

.tab-content:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the # value url like http://example.com#tabs3 .Then use like this in your document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $('#'+ hash).addClass("current");

 $(".tabs li").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".tab-content").hide();
  var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
  $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass("current");
  return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi Sibiraj PR, Thanks for the comment - to confirm: on my index.php I will link the "click here to go to archived docs" to http://documents.php#tab3 and then to make it work I need to add the above two lines to the existing javascript (or does the above 2 lines of javascript code need to replace existing code in my javascript ? Thanks, Reinhard.

Comment: Hi Sibiraj PR, Thanks again for the update. I have tried this, but the moment I add the two additional lines of code in the JavaScript namely `var hash = window.location.hash;` and `$('#'+ hash).addClass("current");` then the link format  **http://documents.php#tabs3** you suggested from my index.php still takes me to the default Tab 1 on documents.php, if I then click on Tab 2, 3 and 4 they do not work any longer (content stays on Tab1). There might be something else missing I guess. Thanks for any further help.

Comment: Good day Sibiraj PR, Sorry, but when I add your suggested changes then the content of the four tabs dissapear and does not show at all. I've made a jsfiddle with exactly the code I am using, would you mind please having a look here http://jsfiddle.net/rrensburg/fLDfy/3/ and see if you add your modified code (JavaScript and HTML) why is then "breaks" the TAB Content please? Thank a lot, Reinhard.

Comment: Hi there Sibiraj PR. I have now copied the new code from the jsfiddle above back into my live site, if one is now on "documents.php" you can click the four tabs and they work again (shows content of tabs fine when clicked) - but still if targeted from index.php it does not target any tabs and ends up at the default tab (tab1), also not "selecting" it (not underlining the tab itself). The URL I tried on index.php was both documents.php#tab3 and documents.php#ttab3 and in both instances one ends up on docuemnts.php at tab1's content. Thanks for assistance iwth the last piece of the puzzle :)

Comment: Hi Sibiraj PR, Just wanted to touch base and see if you've maybe had time to look at the latest comment please. Thanks a lot, Reinhard